# Как вывести информацию о текущем противнике и о своём персонаже?

Tags: python

у меня в игре есть такое меню:
введите nickname персонажа:куку
Выбери действие:
1 - В бой!
2 - Тренировка
3 - Информация об игроке
4 - Информация о текущем противнике
Под числом 3 должна быть информация о персонаже за которого играют, под числом 4 информация о текущем противнике.
вот все коды:
файл:data.py
код:

```
player={
    'name':'',
    'armor':0.95,
    'hp': 10,
    'attack': 2,
    'money': 10000,
    'inventory': [],
    'luck':10,
}
enemies = [{'name': 'Stich', 
            'hp': 105, 
            'attack': 5, 
            'script': '-Чел ты кто? -Я пришёл к своему брату Kadi! -А... ты тот лузер у которого украли секретные документы? -Да! Пусти меня к нему! -Сначало победи меня!', 
            'win': '-Что? как? Ты победил меня! Но до Kadi тебе ещё далеко!', 
            'loss': '-Ну ты и лузер, реально думал меня победить. Проваливай!' 
            },
            {'name': 'MirGrez', 
            'hp': 175, 
            'attack': 10, 
            'script': '-Чувак ты победил Stich чтобы добраться до Kadi! -Да, я сражусь со всеми чтобы добраться до Kadi! -Лучше уходи, а то я тебя в живых не оставлю!', 
            'win': '-Да уж, ты силён! Даю тебе совет- лучше уходи пока тебя не убил самый сильный наш враг DRAGO!', 
            'loss': '-Ха-Ха, иди тренируйся! Слабак!' 
            },
            {'name': 'DRAGO', 
            'hp': 10, 
            'attack': 10, 
            'script': '-Эй! это ты DRAGO? -Да, кто ты такой и как ты сюда попал? -Я победил Stich и MirGrez чтобы попасть к Kadi! -Они ещё те слабаки, так что уходи! у тебя нет шансов одолеть меня!!!', 
            'win': '-Говори, где Kadi? -Он там в соседней комнате...', 
            'loss': '-Я же говорил - тебе меня не одолеть. Уходи и не возвращайся!' 
            }]
```

файл:helpers.py
код:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from data import*

def fight(current_enemy):
    round=randint(1, 2)
    enemy=enemies[current_enemy]
    enemy_hp=enemies[current_enemy]['hp']
    print('Враг', enemy['name'])
    print(enemy['script'])
    input('нажмите на Enter чтобы продолжить')

    while player['hp'] > 0 and enemy_hp > 0:
        if round % 2 == 1:
            print(f'{player["name"]} атакует {enemy["name"]}.')
            enemy_hp -= player['attack']
            sleep(1)
            print(f'''{player['name']} - {player['hp']}
    {enemy['name']} - {enemy_hp}''')
            print()
            sleep(1)
        else:
            print(f'{enemy["name"]} атакует {player["name"]}.')
            player['hp'] -= enemy['attack']
            sleep(1)
            print(f'''{player['name']} - {player['hp']}
    {enemy['name']} - {enemy_hp}''')
            print()
            sleep(1)
        round += 1
        if player['hp'] > 0:
            print(f'Противник - {enemy["name"]}: {enemy["win"]}')
            current_enemy += 1
        else:
            print(f'Противник - {enemy["name"]}: {enemy["loss"]}')
        player['hp'] = 100
        return current_enemy
     
def training(training_type):
    for i in range(0, 101, 20):
        print(f'Тренировка завершена на {i}%')
        sleep(1.5)
    if training_type == '1':
        player['attack'] += 2
        print(f'Тренировка окончена! Теперь ваша величина атаки равна {player["attack"]}')
    elif training_type == '2':
        player['armor'] -= .09
        print(f'Тренировка окончена! Теперь броня поглощает {100 - player["armor"] * 100}% урона')
    print()
```

файл:step.py
код:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from data import*
from helpers import*

name=input('введите nickname персонажа:')
player['name']=name
current_enemy=0

while True:
    action = input('''Выбери действие:
1 - В бой!
2 - Тренировка
3 - Информаиция об игроке
4 - Информация о текущем противнике
''')
    if action == '1':
        current_enemy = fight(current_enemy)
        if current_enemy == 3:
            break
    elif action == '2':
        training_type = input('''1 - тренировать атаку
2 - тренировать оборону
''')
        training(training_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно в step.py дописать нужные строки. show_info(player) для вывода информации о персонаже и функцию show_enemy_info(enemy) для вывода информации о текущем противнике. В этих функциях вы можете использовать информацию из словарей player и enemies соответственно.

step.py

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from data import*
from helpers import*

def show_info(player):
    print(f"Имя: {player['name']}")
    print(f"Броня: {player['armor']}")
    print(f"Здоровье: {player['hp']}")
    print(f"Атака: {player['attack']}")
    print(f"Деньги: {player['money']}")
    print(f"Инвентарь: {player['inventory']}")
    print(f"Удача: {player['luck']}")

def show_enemy_info(enemy):
    print(f"Имя: {enemy['name']}")
    print(f"Здоровье: {enemy['hp']}")
    print(f"Атака: {enemy['attack']}")

name=input('введите nickname персонажа:')
player['name']=name
current_enemy=0

while True:
    action = input('''Выбери действие:
1 - В бой!
2 - Тренировка
3 - Информация об игроке
4 - Информация о текущем противнике
''')
    if action == '1':
        current_enemy = fight(current_enemy)
        if current_enemy == 3:
            break
    elif action == '2':
        training_type = input('''1 - тренировать атаку
2 - тренировать оборону
''')
        training(training_type)
    elif action == '3':
        show_info(player)
    elif action == '4':
        show_enemy_info(enemies[current_enemy])
```